# jQuery on mouseover do something on mouseout revert

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, onmouseover, onmouseout

When you click on the buttons they load the page but on hover I have the following jQuery in a WordPress template which loads my content into a div:

```
jQuery(document).ready(
 function(){
 jQuery("#menu-item-72 a, #menu-item-71 a, #menu-item-70 a,
         #menu-item-69 a, #menu-item-68 a, #menu-item-67 a")
     .mouseover(function () {
       jQuery("#content").load(jQuery(this).attr("href") + " #content");
     });
});
```

I need help in setting the mouseout

So if I am on `site.com/about` and mouseover the menu the content loads in the div then I would like the mouseout to revert to the content for the about page...and so on

Thanks for any help in this

Answer (score 0):

this is a rough solution right here (may need to be optimized):

```
jQuery(function() {
    (function($) {

        //original html storage
        var origHtml = [];

        //create the child selectors 
        var links = [
            '#menu-item-72 a',
            '#menu-item-71 a',
            '#menu-item-70 a',
            '#menu-item-69 a',
            '#menu-item-68 a',
            '#menu-item-67 a'
            ].join(',');

        //use jQuery to apply one handler for all links
        $('nearest_common_parent_to_links').on('mouseover', links, function() {

            var url = $(this).attr("href") + " #content";

            //remove the original content and store
            origHtml = $("#content").children().detach();

            //load your custom content                
            $("#content").load(url);

        }).on('mouseout', links, function() {

            //restore original html
            $("#content").html(origHtml);

        });
    }(jQuery));
});​
```

Comment: Wow nicely commented reply, thanks Joseph I will try the solution today.

Comment: you can set breakpoints and check if `origHtml` contains the original contents, try to check if remote content was loaded using `.load()` and check the console. i can't really test this one myself.